# AttributeError: LstmNetwork instance has no attribute 'x_list_add'

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, attributeerror

I have two python files namely `lstm.py` and `test.py` in same folder. im executing the `test.py` file in python interactive shell. It shows the

> AttributeError: Lstm Param instance has no attribute "x_list_add".

**lstm.py**

```
import random

import numpy as np
import math

def sigmoid(x): 
    return 1. / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(values): 
    return values*(1-values)

def tanh_derivative(values): 
    return 1. - values ** 2

# createst uniform random array w/ values in [a,b) and shape args
def rand_arr(a, b, *args): 
np.random.seed(0)
return np.random.rand(*args) * (b - a) + a

class LstmParam:
def __init__(self, mem_cell_ct, x_dim):
self.mem_cell_ct = mem_cell_ct
    self.x_dim = x_dim
    concat_len = x_dim + mem_cell_ct
    # weight matrices
    self.wg = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct, concat_len)
    self.wi = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct, concat_len) 
    self.wf = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct, concat_len)
    self.wo = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct, concat_len)
    # bias terms
    self.bg = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct) 
    self.bi = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct) 
    self.bf = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct) 
    self.bo = rand_arr(-0.1, 0.1, mem_cell_ct) 
    # diffs (derivative of loss function w.r.t. all parameters)
    self.wg_diff = np.zeros((mem_cell_ct, concat_len)) 
    self.wi_diff = np.zeros((mem_cell_ct, concat_len)) 
    self.wf_diff = np.zeros((mem_cell_ct, concat_len)) 
    self.wo_diff = np.zeros((mem_cell_ct, concat_len)) 
    self.bg_diff = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct) 
    self.bi_diff = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct) 
    self.bf_diff = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct) 
    self.bo_diff = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct)

def apply_diff(self, lr = 1):
    self.wg -= lr * self.wg_diff
    self.wi -= lr * self.wi_diff
    self.wf -= lr * self.wf_diff
    self.wo -= lr * self.wo_diff
    self.bg -= lr * self.bg_diff
    self.bi -= lr * self.bi_diff
    self.bf -= lr * self.bf_diff
    self.bo -= lr * self.bo_diff
    # reset diffs to zero
    self.wg_diff = np.zeros_like(self.wg)
    self.wi_diff = np.zeros_like(self.wi) 
    self.wf_diff = np.zeros_like(self.wf) 
    self.wo_diff = np.zeros_like(self.wo) 
    self.bg_diff = np.zeros_like(self.bg)
    self.bi_diff = np.zeros_like(self.bi) 
    self.bf_diff = np.zeros_like(self.bf) 
    self.bo_diff = np.zeros_like(self.bo) 

class LstmState:
    def __init__(self, mem_cell_ct, x_dim):
        self.g = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct)
        self.i = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct)
        self.f = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct)
        self.o = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct)
        self.s = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct)
        self.h = np.zeros(mem_cell_ct)
        self.bottom_diff_h = np.zeros_like(self.h)
        self.bottom_diff_s = np.zeros_like(self.s)

class LstmNode:
   def __init__(self, lstm_param, lstm_state):
        # store reference to parameters and to activations
        self.state = lstm_state
        self.param = lstm_param
        # non-recurrent input concatenated with recurrent input
        self.xc = None

def bottom_data_is(self, x, s_prev = None, h_prev = None):
# if this is the first lstm node in the network
if s_prev is None: s_prev = np.zeros_like(self.state.s)
    if h_prev is None: h_prev = np.zeros_like(self.state.h)
    # save data for use in backprop
    self.s_prev = s_prev
    self.h_prev = h_prev
    # concatenate x(t) and h(t-1)
    xc = np.hstack((x,  h_prev))
    self.state.g = np.tanh(np.dot(self.param.wg, xc) + self.param.bg)
    self.state.i = sigmoid(np.dot(self.param.wi, xc) + self.param.bi)
    self.state.f = sigmoid(np.dot(self.param.wf, xc) + self.param.bf)
    self.state.o = sigmoid(np.dot(self.param.wo, xc) + self.param.bo)
    self.state.s = self.state.g * self.state.i + s_prev * self.state.f
    self.state.h = self.state.s * self.state.o
    self.xc = xc

def top_diff_is(self, top_diff_h, top_diff_s):
    # notice that top_diff_s is carried along the constant error carousel
    ds = self.state.o * top_diff_h + top_diff_s
    do = self.state.s * top_diff_h
    di = self.state.g * ds
    dg = self.state.i * ds
    df = self.s_prev * ds
    # diffs w.r.t. vector inside sigma / tanh function
    di_input = sigmoid_derivative(self.state.i) * di 
    df_input = sigmoid_derivative(self.state.f) * df 
    do_input = sigmoid_derivative(self.state.o) * do 
    dg_input = tanh_derivative(self.state.g) * dg

    # diffs w.r.t. inputs
    self.param.wi_diff += np.outer(di_input, self.xc)
    self.param.wf_diff += np.outer(df_input, self.xc)
    self.param.wo_diff += np.outer(do_input, self.xc)
    self.param.wg_diff += np.outer(dg_input, self.xc)
    self.param.bi_diff += di_input
    self.param.bf_diff += df_input       
    self.param.bo_diff += do_input
    self.param.bg_diff += dg_input       
    # compute bottom diff
    dxc = np.zeros_like(self.xc)
    dxc += np.dot(self.param.wi.T, di_input)
    dxc += np.dot(self.param.wf.T, df_input)
    dxc += np.dot(self.param.wo.T, do_input)
    dxc += np.dot(self.param.wg.T, dg_input)

    # save bottom diffs
    self.state.bottom_diff_s = ds * self.state.f
    self.state.bottom_diff_h = dxc[self.param.x_dim:]

class LstmNetwork():
    def __init__(self, lstm_param):
        self.lstm_param = lstm_param
        self.lstm_node_list = []
        # input sequence
        self.x_list = []

    def y_list_is(self, y_list, loss_layer):
    """
    Updates diffs by setting target sequence 
    with corresponding loss layer. 
    Will *NOT* update parameters.  To update parameters,
    call self.lstm_param.apply_diff()
    """
        assert len(y_list) == len(self.x_list)
        idx = len(self.x_list) - 1
    # first node only gets diffs from label ...
        loss = loss_layer.loss(self.lstm_node_list[idx].state.h,                   y_list[idx])
    diff_h = loss_layer.bottom_diff(self.lstm_node_list[idx].state.h, y_list[idx])
    # here s is not affecting loss due to h(t+1), hence we set equal to zero
    diff_s = np.zeros(self.lstm_param.mem_cell_ct)
    self.lstm_node_list[idx].top_diff_is(diff_h, diff_s)
    idx -= 1
    ### ... following nodes also get diffs from next nodes, hence we add diffs to diff_h
    ### we also propagate error along constant error carousel using diff_s
    while idx >= 0:
        loss += loss_layer.loss(self.lstm_node_list[idx].state.h, y_list[idx])
        diff_h = loss_layer.bottom_diff(self.lstm_node_list[idx].state.h, y_list[idx])
        diff_h += self.lstm_node_list[idx + 1].state.bottom_diff_h
        diff_s = self.lstm_node_list[idx + 1].state.bottom_diff_s
        self.lstm_node_list[idx].top_diff_is(diff_h, diff_s)
        idx -= 1 
    return loss

def x_list_clear(self):
self.x_list = []

def x_list_add(self, x):
    self.x_list.append(x)
    if len(self.x_list) > len(self.lstm_node_list):
        # need to add new lstm node, create new state mem
        lstm_state = LstmState(self.lstm_param.mem_cell_ct,             self.lstm_param.x_dim)
        self.lstm_node_list.append(LstmNode(self.lstm_param, lstm_state))
    # get index of most recent x input
    idx = len(self.x_list) - 1
    if idx == 0:
       # no recurrent inputs yet
       self.lstm_node_list[idx].bottom_data_is(x)
    else:
        s_prev = self.lstm_node_list[idx - 1].state.s
        h_prev = self.lstm_node_list[idx - 1].state.h
        self.lstm_node_list[idx].bottom_data_is(x, s_prev, h_prev)
```

**test.py**

```
import numpy as np
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/vj/Downloads/tfdeep/core_lstm/lstm/")
from lstm import LstmParam, LstmNetwork


class ToyLossLayer:
"""
Computes square loss with first element of hidden layer array."""
        #classmethod
    def loss(self, pred, label):
        return (pred[0] - label) ** 2

#classmethod
def bottom_diff(self, pred, label):
    diff = np.zeros_like(pred)
    diff[0] = 2 * (pred[0] - label)
    return diff


def example_0():
    # learns to repeat simple sequence from random inputs
    np.random.seed(0)
    # parameters for input data dimension and lstm cell count
    mem_cell_ct = 100
    x_dim = 50
    lstm_param = LstmParam(mem_cell_ct, x_dim)
    lstm_net = LstmNetwork(lstm_param)
    y_list = [-0.5, 0.2, 0.1, -0.5]
    input_val_arr = [np.random.random(x_dim) for _ in y_list]
    for cur_iter in range(100):
    print("iter", "%2s" % str(cur_iter),": ")
        for ind in range(len(y_list)):
            lstm_net.x_list_add(input_val_arr[ind])
        #print("y_pred = [" + ", ".join(["% 2.5f" % lstm_net.lstm_node_list[ind].state.h[0] for ind in range(len(y_list))]) +"]," end=":")
        loss = lstm_net.y_list_is(y_list, ToyLossLayer)
        print("loss:", "%.3e" % loss)
        lstm_param.apply_diff(lr=0.1)
        lstm_net.x_list_clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    example_0()
```

while executing this test.py file I am getting I getting the follwing error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 2, in 
>         File "", line 14, in example_0
>       AttributeError: LstmNetwork instance has no attribute 'x_list_add'

I am struggling to get the output. I didnot get any post relate to my problem.

Comment: Dear stackoverflow members thanks for your support. I rectified this problem . I defined the function out of the class .

Comment: I had another problem in the test.py file where loss= lstm_net.y_list_is(y_list,ToyLossLayer)  is throwing the name error: global name ToyLossLayer is not defined.... Please help me to solve this.